# Why did the loss of CNN model change little throughout the whole epoch？

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running a deep learning project about visual speech recognition tasks, and I found a strange phenomenon.
In the first several epochs, the loss can decrease at a normal speed. I mean, in a epoch, the loss would decrease with the increase of the number of iterations. While in the later epochs, the loss almost unchanged in the whole epoch, but would decrease at the start of the next epoch.

Sometimes I interrupted the running code after an epoch finishing and restart from the trained weights. The loss would decrease at the start of the next epoch, too.

This is the training code:

```py
    for epoch in range(283,args.epochs):

        model.train()
        running_loss, running_corrects, running_all, cer = 0., 0., 0., 0.

        for batch_idx, sample_batched in enumerate(dset_loaders['train']):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs,targets,lengths,y_lengths,idx = sample_batched
            inputs = inputs.float()     
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(device) , targets.to(device) 
            outputs = model(inputs)  
            loss = criterion(F.log_softmax(outputs,dim=-1),targets,lengths,y_lengths)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            decoded = decoder.decode_greedy(outputs,lengths)
            cursor, gt = 0, []
            for b in range(inputs.size(0)):
                y_str = ''.join([vocabularies[ch] for ch in targets[cursor: cursor + y_lengths[b]]])
                gt.append(y_str)
                cursor += y_lengths[b]
            CER = decoder.cer_batch(decoded,gt)
            cer += CER
            cer_mean = cer/(batch_idx+1)

            running_loss += loss.data * inputs.size(0)
            running_all += len(inputs)
            if batch_idx == 0:
                since = time.time()      
            else (batch_idx+1) % args.interval == 0 or (batch_idx == len(dset_loaders['train'])-1):            
                print('Process: [{:5.0f}/{:5.0f} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.4f}\tcer:{:.4f}\tCost time:{:5.0f}s\tEstimated time:{:5.0f}s\t'.format(
                    running_all,
                    len(dset_loaders['train'].dataset),
                    100. * batch_idx / (len(dset_loaders['train'])-1),
                    running_loss / running_all,
                    cer_mean,
                    time.time()-since,
                    (time.time()-since)*(len(dset_loaders['train'])-1) / batch_idx - (time.time()-since)))
        print('{} Epoch:\t{:2}\tLoss: {:.4f}\tcer:{:.4f}\t'.format(
            'pretrain',
            epoch,
            running_loss / len(dset_loaders['train'].dataset),
            cer_mean)+'\n')
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path+'/'+args.mode+'_'+str(epoch+1)+'.pt')
```

I get very confused about this phenomenon. I think if the Loss hasn't changed in the whole epoch, the Loss in the next epoch shouldn't have changed either. Why the Loss still change at the beginning of the next epoch after unchanged in the whole epoch?
Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to how you print the loss.

You have a `running_loss` that denotes the total loss for every data point calculated in this epoch and a `running_all` demote the total number of data points calculated in this epoch. You print the `running_loss / running_all` which is the average loss for every data point in this epoch.

As more data point is collected, even if the loss is steadily decreasing, the new loss is averaged with a larger number of the previously computed loss, which make the decreasing seems slower. Explained here: https://gist.github.com/valkjsaaa/b0b26075174a87b3fd302b4b52ab035a

I would suggest replace `running_loss / running_all` with `loss.data / len(inputs)`, which is the loss for this current batch and see if it would help.

The changed code should look like the following:

```
   for epoch in range(283,args.epochs):

        model.train()
        running_loss, running_corrects, running_all, cer = 0., 0., 0., 0.

        for batch_idx, sample_batched in enumerate(dset_loaders['train']):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs,targets,lengths,y_lengths,idx = sample_batched
            inputs = inputs.float()     
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(device) , targets.to(device) 
            outputs = model(inputs)  
            loss = criterion(F.log_softmax(outputs,dim=-1),targets,lengths,y_lengths)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            decoded = decoder.decode_greedy(outputs,lengths)
            cursor, gt = 0, []
            for b in range(inputs.size(0)):
                y_str = ''.join([vocabularies[ch] for ch in targets[cursor: cursor + y_lengths[b]]])
                gt.append(y_str)
                cursor += y_lengths[b]
            CER = decoder.cer_batch(decoded,gt)
            cer += CER
            cer_mean = cer/(batch_idx+1)

            running_loss += loss.data * inputs.size(0)
            running_all += len(inputs)
            if batch_idx == 0:
                since = time.time()      
            else (batch_idx+1) % args.interval == 0 or (batch_idx == len(dset_loaders['train'])-1):            
                print('Process: [{:5.0f}/{:5.0f} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.4f}\tcer:{:.4f}\tCost time:{:5.0f}s\tEstimated time:{:5.0f}s\t'.format(
                    running_all,
                    len(dset_loaders['train'].dataset),
                    100. * batch_idx / (len(dset_loaders['train'])-1),
                    loss.data,
                    cer_mean,
                    time.time()-since,
                    (time.time()-since)*(len(dset_loaders['train'])-1) / batch_idx - (time.time()-since)))
        print('{} Epoch:\t{:2}\tLoss: {:.4f}\tcer:{:.4f}\t'.format(
            'pretrain',
            epoch,
            running_loss / len(dset_loaders['train'].dataset),
            cer_mean)+'\n')
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path+'/'+args.mode+'_'+str(epoch+1)+'.pt')
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the loss for  current batch should be `loss.data` rather than `loss.data / len(inputs)`. I tried to print the batch-loss, and the batch-loss is not stable, which is sometimes big and sometimes small. And why the loss decreased a lot at the next epoch? For example, the loss is stable at 0.8 in the whole 20th epoch, while it becomes 0.7 at the 21th epoch, and stable at 0.7 the whole 21th epoch.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Your way of computing average loss caused the wierd behavior, as explained here: https://gist.github.com/valkjsaaa/b0b26075174a87b3fd302b4b52ab035a

Comment: I also suggests you to output the loss to TensorboardX. TensorboardX provides a correct way to smooth out your loss.